# Portlet block jsp pages

Tags: java, portlet

I have a problem with portlet. When i write in `portlet.xml` standart line

```
<portlet-class>com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet</portlet-class>
```

my jsp pages works fine. But when im add my portlet-class

```
<portlet-class>test.uploadport</portlet-class>
```

java code in jsp page dont execute. Im not talking about `view.jsp` im talk about pages which called from `view.jsp`.

I think problem in doView() from portlet

uploadport.java

```
package test;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.portlet.*;


import org.apache.commons.fileupload.*;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.portlet.*;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.*;
public class uploadport extends GenericPortlet {
private String error;
public void doView(RenderRequest req, RenderResponse res)
throws IOException, PortletException
{
 WindowState state = req.getWindowState();
 res.setContentType("text/html");
 PortletSession session = req.getPortletSession(true);
 PortletContext context = getPortletContext();
 PortletRequestDispatcher rd;
 rd = context.getRequestDispatcher("/view.jsp");
 rd.include(req, res);

}
public void processAction(ActionRequest req, ActionResponse res)
throws IOException, PortletException
{
System.out.println("VASAY - PIROZJOK");
    PortletSession session = req.getPortletSession(true);
    DiskFileItemFactory diskFileItemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    PortletFileUpload portletFileUpload = new PortletFileUpload(diskFileItemFactory);
    List<FileItem> list=null;
    String mifpath= "1";
    String path = " ";
    String mif = " ";
    String from = "\\\\";
    String to ="/";
    String error="";
    try{
        list = portletFileUpload.parseRequest(req);
        Iterator<FileItem> it = list.iterator();
        //response.setContentType("text/html");
       while ( it.hasNext() ) 
       {

          FileItem item = (FileItem) it.next();
          File disk = new File("C:/uploaded_files/"+item.getName());

    path = disk.toString();

    String code = new String(path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("."), path.length()).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"utf-8");
    if (code.equalsIgnoreCase(".zip"))
    {
        System.out.println("PIROZJOK");
        mifpath=path;
        mif = mifpath.replaceAll(from, to);
        item.write(disk);
        error=unzip.unpack(mif, "C:/uploaded_files");
    }
    else
    {
        error = "Выбранный файл не является архивом zip";

    }
  }
}
 catch ( Exception e ) {
 log( "Upload Error" , e);
} 

}
 private void log(String string, Exception e)
   {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Why its heppening?

Comment: Does it enter the `doView`? Btw: having `error` as an instance variable won't work correctly - your portlet must be thread safe...

Comment: My english is bad. If i understand u correctly u say that nothing in this portlet cant influence on jsp pages?

Comment: NP. I just wonder if the `doView` is executed at all. Add something like a log statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was particullary solved.
1. need to use `MVC portlet` not `Generic Portlet`
2. delete `doView()` from portlet

That all. But thare is anther problems.
1. `MVC portlet` not a best choise.
2. How to send parametrs to `view.jsp` from portlet without `doView()`?